# How to refresh SDCard?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am trying to refresh SDCard. For this i am using

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

But it is giving error. Here is my LOG.

```
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{amiTechnologies.products.amidesignerforvideo/amiTechnologies.products.amidesignerforvideo.AMIDesignerForVideoActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=5093, uid=10156
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=5093, uid=10156
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2373)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1127)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:365)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at amiTechnologies.products.amidesignerforvideo.AMIDesignerForVideoActivity.onCreate(AMIDesignerForVideoActivity.java:329)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-11 04:19:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     ... 11 more
```

What permission that i have to add? I tried many answers from stack overflow, but did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

as you are using the code

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

which looks good but The device must be disconnected from USB, it should not be connected. Otherwise you may need to unplug and plug the device again to see all those changes you are trying to do.

did you seen the log it stated that

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
```

please disconnect the device while you are using following code snippet in action

also visit [I try scan media file in sdcard and refresh it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409224/i-try-scan-media-file-in-sdcard-and-refresh-it) which may help you.

Comment: Thank u jitesh, Let me try your suggestion

Comment: Surprised thing is Even though USB is connected, this code is working without failure... :)

Comment: I have one more problem.. I have made changes on my SD Card, then my app did not recognize changes. I restarted my app it is recognizing changes. How can i solve this.

Comment: Just look at this you will come to know what exactly my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303974/video-thumbnails-not-refreshing